# lubridate: Strip milliseconds when reading datetime objects

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate, milliseconds

I have a situation where dates are written like this, with milliseconds:

```
2021/03/04 11:15:19.000
2021/03/04 11:15:19.999
```

I convert them to datetimes with lubridate and they look good and exactly the same:

```
> library(lubridate)
> as_datetime("2021/03/04 11:15:19.000")
[1] "2021-03-04 11:15:19 UTC"
> as_datetime("2021/03/04 11:15:19.999")
[1] "2021-03-04 11:15:19 UTC"
```

However, when I compare them they are not equivalent:

```
> as_datetime("2021/03/04 11:15:19.000") == as_datetime("2021/03/04 11:15:19.999")
[1] FALSE
```

But if simple dates, they are:

```
> as_date("2021/03/04 11:15:19.000") == as_date("2021/03/04 11:15:19.999")
[1] TRUE
```

Which creates problems for my workflow. It is particularly difficult to troubleshoot because there is no way to know that the milliseconds were different when simply looking at the processed dates because milliseconds don't show. Is there a way to have them read as equivalent datetimes?

My best workaround is to transform to character because they are equivalent in their character form:

```
> as.character(as_datetime("2021/03/04 11:15:19.000")) == 
  as.character(as_datetime("2021/03/04 11:15:19.999"))
[1] TRUE
```

From this we can convert to datetimes again:

```
> as_datetime(as.character(as_datetime("2021/03/04 11:15:19.000"))) ==
  as_datetime(as.character(as_datetime("2021/03/04 11:15:19.999")))
[1] TRUE
```

But this solution seems really convoluted. Surely there is a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Check with the `strftime` or `format`, the milliseconds precision is already there, but not printed i.e. `strftime(as_datetime("2021/03/04 11:15:19.000"), "%OS3")
[1] "19.000";
> strftime(as_datetime("2021/03/04 11:15:19.999"), "%OS3")
[1] "19.999"`

Comment: Skip the lubridate function and use base R to define the time conversion: `as.POSIXct(yourdates, "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S", tz="")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

R stores datetime objects as a `double` counting the fractional seconds since the epoch (i.e Jan 1, 1970).  Note that we said fractional seconds.  Your two observations *were* different when you read them, so R is quite correct in telling you that they are not equal.

But converting to `Date` (which is a count of *days* rather than seconds since the epoch) you are doing a lossy conversion.  A simpler way would have been `trunc()`.  As @akrun and @Dave2e hinted in the comments above, none of this has anything to do with `lubridate` -- it is simply how R does business.

```
> d1 <- as.POSIXct("2021/03/04 11:15:19.000")
> d2 <- as.POSIXct("2021/03/04 11:15:19.999")
> d1 == d2
[1] FALSE
> trunc(d1) == trunc(d2)
[1] TRUE
>
```